# Indicate that a Func/Proc throws an Exception (like Java). Best Practice?

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception

I'm relative new to PLSQL but I have a background in Java.
Because of this I've wondered if there is an elegant way to write Procedures or Functions which indicate the Exceptions they are raising or at least that they are raising Exceptions.

I've already thought of an Suffix for the Procedure names, e.g. proc_name_ex but I'm not quite happy with that.

Thanks in advance for ideas! :)

Comment: Won't almost all procedures and functions end up with an _ex suffix? How will this be useful? Perhaps you could explain the thinking in more detail for those of us who don't know Java.

Answer (score 0):

The only language construct that allows you to indicate if a subprogram raises an exception is a [comment](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS203).

However there is a language construct that guarantees a subprogram raises no exception - `when others` [exception handler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/exception_handler.htm#LNPLS01316) that is guaranteed to trap all exceptions:

```
declare
  a pls_integer;
begin
  a := 1/0;
exception -- exception section
  when others then --exception handler
    -- here you should process the exception in some clever way that
    -- makes sense in the context
end;
/
```

I don't recommend to encode exception information into subprogram names.